# Unable to parse Delimiter of type \u0003 while reading Text file in Databricks(Scala)

Tags: scala, databricks

I have a text file with messages which has multiple delimiters of type \u0003, \u0002 etc. I am using the Split function while loading data into Rdd but I am unable to remove the delimiters. When I change the Delimiter from \u0003 to just u0003 the split function seems to work for rdd but then I am left with an extra \..

I saw some solutions and they mention the below code should work.

```
val input = sc.textFile("filename.txt").map(_.split("\u0003"))

input.collect()
```

I just get the entire string without the delimiters removed

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[4031] at map at command-1662719304326521:7
res24: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array({"GDSFE001\u00031\u0003N\u00030\u0003Confirm_Shipment_Closed\u00035572214\u0003B\u0003I7EPM0XV1Z8KB\u0003TAG0000\u0001\u000220190516\u00011409\u0001GCSS\u0001Message Broker\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001O\u0001\u0001\u0001N\u0001BKG\u0001\u0001\u0001\u000163.0\u0002TAGT100\u0001HDZKG4XV1Z9KB\u0001BNILG4XV1Z9KB.................................
```

Comment: What happens if you split with  "\\u0003"?

Comment: @Tim Same result only u0003 seems to work

Comment: I also have the similar code in PySpark and this seems to work just fine 

input = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/IIB_downloaded_test.txt").map(lambda x: x.split("\u0003"))

Comment: \u0003 is char. You can split by Char (not String) to avoid problem with escaping

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying some other combinations and this seems to work

```
val input = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/IIB_downloaded_test.txt").map(_.split("""\\u0003"""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two solutions:

```
//For a dataframe or dataset
val dataFrame = spark.read.option("delimiter", """\\u0003""").textFile("path")

//For an rdd
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("path").map(_.split("""\\u0003"""))
```

The reason "\u0003" does not work, but """\u0003""" is needed, is because the double quote escapes the character and it reads as escaped \u
whereas the three double quotes treats the entire \u0003 as the separator string.

Comment: val dataFrame = spark.read.option("delimiter", """\\u0003""").textFile("path") doesnt seem to work

Comment: Could you please comment here two lines of your data? so I can get a way to work directly with datasets using the data, instead of going via rdd or map